Which file indicates the completion of YOLOv7 model training? [Assumption: I am unable to view the training logs]
I am using Optuna to optimize the hyperparameters of a YOLOv7 model. Because of the way Optuna operates, I cannot examine the output after the training is complete. Therefore, I would like to know if a file is generated at the conclusion of the model's training, so that I can trigger Optuna accordingly.
I checked the output after a set period, but I'd like to know if there is a better way.
